# Denodo Dive Split function URL

Tags: regex, split, denodo, vql

I'm trying the below code to select the last part of the URL:

```sql
select 'http://www.XX.com/download/apple-Selection-products/beauty-soap-ICs' ,  field_1[0].string
from
(
select SPLIT('([^\/]+$)', 'http://www.XX.com/download/apple-Selection-products/beauty-soap-ICs')field_1 

  )
```

However, my result isn't coming as expected.

```
http://www.XX.com/download/apple-Selection-products/beauty-soap-ICs
```

result should be :

```
beauty-soap-ICs
```

but I'm getting [Wrong Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sqbK.png).

Any help will be appreciated. The URL can and can't end in a `/`.

Comment: Try `SELECT REGEXP('http://www.XX.com/download/apple-Selection-products/beauty-soap-ICs', '.*/(.)', '$1') AS result`

Comment: works, thanks, but if it has 'http://www.XX.com/download/apple-Selection-products/beauty-soap-ICs/' in end , how to remove that and something that works for both case

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`REGEXP` function](https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/6.0/vdp/vql/appendix/syntax_of_condition_functions/text_processing_functions#regexp) here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP('http://www.XX.com/download/apple-Selection-products/beauty-soap-ICs', '.*/([^/]+)/?$', '$1') AS result
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t5BHCy/1)

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to this group value)" one or more chars other than `/`
- `/?` - an optional `/` char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Hi , i just checked this, the results were showing /1 for the sample

Comment: @guess_work0205 Not sure what sample you have in mind. [It works on your samples posted here](https://regex101.com/r/t5BHCy/1).